# How to use .net cil jmp opcode

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I'm trying to get the jmp opcode to work in Cil

```
jmp  void ILTest.Program::MyFunc2(int32)
```

ilasm is fine with it, but when I run the program I always get "common language runtime detects an invalid program" exception.

I know this is unverifiable code so I have tried to give permissions

`SecurityPermission perm =
              new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution |
                       SecurityPermissionFlag.SkipVerification |
                       SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode);`

but it does not seem to have any effect.

Has anyone got a program using 'jmp' working?

Comment: Could you show us your actual code that we could try?

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 5):

[`jmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.jmp.aspx) can only jump to a method with the same arguments as the current method. Make sure you're already in a method taking an `int32` as a parameter, and that you've nothing pushed on the stack: it must be empty. Also ensure you're not in a `try/catch/filter/finally` block.

If you can't meet those criteria, use a `call` instead.

Comment: the jmped to method has same signature as calling method.

Comment: What about the stack? Also make sure you're not in an exception handling block.

Comment: i'm just experimenting so very simple code. I had working code with a 'call' and just replaced it with a 'jmp'. I'm sure the problem is that the jmp instruction is unverifiable. If anybody has a working example that would be great. I need to use jmp in my actual system because there is no chance to unwind the stack.

Comment: @WilliamPearson What do you mean, “there is no chance to unwind the stack”? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks dude, you've just answered  question I've had all day, I'm linking to your answer

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind is that all assemblies and dynamicmethods have their own sets of metadata tokens, that are used to reference other methods, fields, and types. So when replacing IL code of an existing assembly you can only use tokens that have already been used in that assembly (in other classes and methods). Most likely you cannot allocate new tokens after assembly has already been built. (at least it's my hunch)

Also I think there are two ways of "jumping" from one assembly to another. One is using DynamicMethod.Invoke, another is prebuilding a dummy method, and parsing destination method token from it's IL code. In my project I ended up needing both, so good luck. :)

Also when replacing an existing method's IL code you need to have big enough "max stack" value, and somehow make sure that there's enough local variables for your new code.

Unfortunately .net runtime exceptions are really generic, and never tell you what went wrong. So, be prepared for having lots of small test cases, for testing your solutions on various methods.

Here's also some useful links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14058/Parsing-the-IL-of-a-Method-Body

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haibo_luo/archive/2006/11/07/turn-methodinfo-to-dynamicmethod.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Content/ViewAssociatedFile.aspx?rzp=%2Fkb%2Fdotnet%2Fdotnetinternals_injection%2Frbcoree.zip&zep=rbcoree%2Frbcoree.cpp&obid=26060&obtid=2&ovid=1

https://www.google.fi/search?num=100&es_sm=93&q=CORINFO_METHOD_INFO&oq=CORINFO_METHOD_INFO&gs_l=serp.3...0.0.0.4517435.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.serp..0.0.0.cdFZu2hO9Yo

Comment: It seems like you've spent a lot of time on dynamic methods and felt like sharing your experiences, wrote up an answer, and then started looking for a question that might possibly benefit from it. That's not necessarily a bad idea, but you picked a wrong question, your answer doesn't actually relate well to this question. If that's not what you were doing, then you've likely simply misunderstood the question, but your answer still doesn't relate well.

Comment: Heh, lots of assumptions in my very specific answer to a very generic question. Still not the worse of my blunders. :)