# reflection emit push and additional argument on evaluation stack

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection.emit

I have working code to create a proxy for a function:

```
// For this controller, I only want a Get method to server Get request
MethodBuilder myGetMethod =
    tb.DefineMethod("Get",
        MethodAttributes.Public,
        typeof(String), new Type[] { typeof(String) });

// Define parameters
myGetMethod.DefineParameter(
    position: 1, // 0 is the return value, 1 is the 1st param, 2 is 2nd, etc.
    attributes: ParameterAttributes.None,
    strParamName: "stringParam"
);

ILGenerator myMethodIL = myGetMethod.GetILGenerator();
Func<string, string> method = (v) => "Poop";
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Jmp, method.Method);
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I would like to expand the func to take in a dependency. e.g

```
Func<string, string, string> method = (v, s) => v + s + "Poop";

myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, "Hi");
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Jmp, method.Method);
myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I'm trying to push the loaded string onto the evaluation stack, Prior to this the evaluation stack already has the input parameter loaded so when calling the jump the parameters align fine.  But now that my func needs to take in an additional argument I need to push the loaded string on the stack.  However when I run this I get an error:

> Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

How do I pop an additional argument on the evaluation stack before calling my proxy?

Comment: Maybe you want to Call your Method ? You cannot Jump to a Method, you can only jump to a Label.

Comment: Why do you use Expressions and Emitting opcodes in mix ? Do one or the other. You want to build an entire class ? But this is only useful if the class has instance fields. But an expression is a static method and can never access instance fields. So if all your methods are static, you get along with expressions, if it has to be instance methods, you have to express the entire logic in OpCodes.
You can also not pass your "this" pointer to the expression, cause the type is not known at compile-time.

Comment: @Holger the jump statement currently works, I tried using call and virt call but nothing would work in the compiler.  The method provides the ilbytes.  I'm using funcs in the example because I'm using this to create dynamic controllers and i want to provide a way for users to expose their own define methods dynamically.  So they pass a func

Comment: Okay so I found out some more info on my [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12141193/1938988) Jmp statements can only forward if the arguments are the same

Comment: A jump has no arguments. A Jump is something to realize a loop ("for", "while") or an "If". ("goto" in C#) Expressions do the same thing as ILCode  - creating something at runtime, but It's higher level, so less easy to make mistakes. At some point you call your LambdaExpression.Compile and you have your runnable ILCode. The very same thing.But Expressions are made to have only one solitaire standalone method at a time. While with TypeBuilder/MethodBuilder you can reproduce an entire class with fields, instance methods. etc. If you don't want this, you go better with Expressions.

Comment: @Holger I was trying to use expressions last week. I had an [open bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58828401/1938988).  That's how I got to where I am.  Plus expressions are very limited and will be hard to expose from the controllers the way I want

Comment: Expressions expose a Delegate and are very simple to use. To the outside, it doesn't make a difference. There are not many limitations, everything you can  express in a C# lambda,you can also create as an expression tree.
But you don't need to know all the interiour stack design. With Opcodes, you don't even have a check you pass two arguments to an 'add' functions.
Expression check you have two arguments, although the type check is not done at compile time, just at runtime. But it's done. 
Maybe you just define the C#-Code you would generate at runtime, and we convert it to an expression

Comment: I use OpCodes for super-high-performance code. The 'Compilation' is much faster, but this is 1ms vs. 10ms or so, not to mention if you don't do it a thousand times.

Comment: I'm basically trying to allow a user to expose additional functions based on a generic controller.  e.g I have a controller which defines Crud operations.  I want a user to be able to just say `AddDynamicFunc<string, string>("echo", key => key)` and the controller will automatically expose the func,  I'm not sure how to expose dynamic controller method like this other than emit il

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Jump statements only work when forwarding the same arguments, instead of figuring out how to write the proper IL I just inject what I need from the DI Container Now.

```
public static Type CompileResultType(string typeSignature, Dictionary<string, string> propDic)
{
    TypeBuilder tb = GetTypeBuilder(typeSignature);

    tb.SetParent(typeof(DynamicControllerBase));

    ConstructorBuilder ctor = tb.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName);

    foreach (var item in propDic)
    {
        CreateProperty(tb, item.Key, Type.GetType(item.Value));
    }

    // For this controller, I only want a Get method to server Get request
    MethodBuilder myGetMethod =
        tb.DefineMethod("Get",
            MethodAttributes.Public,
            typeof(String), new Type[] { typeof(Test), typeof(String) });

    // Define parameters
    var parameterBuilder = myGetMethod.DefineParameter(
        position: 1, // 0 is the return value, 1 is the 1st param, 2 is 2nd, etc.
        attributes: ParameterAttributes.None,
        strParamName: "test"
    );
    var attributeBuilder
        = new CustomAttributeBuilder(typeof(FromServicesAttribute).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), Type.EmptyTypes);
    parameterBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attributeBuilder);

    // Define parameters
    myGetMethod.DefineParameter(
        position: 2, // 0 is the return value, 1 is the 1st param, 2 is 2nd, etc.
        attributes: ParameterAttributes.None,
        strParamName: "stringParam"
    );

    // Generate IL for method.
    ILGenerator myMethodIL = myGetMethod.GetILGenerator();
    Func<string, string> method = (v) => "Poop";

    Func<Test, string, string> method1 = (v, s) => v.Name + s;

    myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Jmp, method1.Method);
    myMethodIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return tb.CreateType();
}
```